# Dell Inspiron n5110 touchpad stop working after upgrate to 13.04

Tags: dell, touchpad, 13.04, inspiron, synaptics

I've recently upgraded to 13.04 and touchpad partially stop working on my Dell Inspiron n5110.
The left and right buttons still working but motions and taps don't.

The system does detect my touchpad

```
→ xinput list                          
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Mouse                                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and I can disable/enable it via `Fn+F3` hotkey or via `→ xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 1` or in system settings:

[image]

Touchpad in my devises:

```
→ cat /proc/bus/input/devices 

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0008 Version=0500
N: Name="AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event9 
B: PROP=8
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 0 70000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2608000 1000003
```

I've tried to debug it using `evtest /dev/input/event9` and I can see noise at log file while touching touchpad.

Got someone any ideas how to fix that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: i have same Dell Inspiron n5110 core i7, did clean installation of ubuntu 13.04, every freakin thing working 100 % , Ubuntu 13.04 Rocks *****..

Comment: Excuse me. What did you do to fix that?

Comment: i did clean installation and you did upgrade .....download Ubuntu 13.04 make live USB and check ur stuff is working or not .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in my earlier comments, only clean installation of Ubuntu 13.04 will work.

Comment: You mean that upgrade OS is not working while installing it is ?

Comment: yes ....most of people having the same issue ..

Answer (score 0):

You should always make a clean install. Its time consuming but its the best way to upgrade, lot of things change between versions and overwriting with new Sistem Files may result in a mess.

Always make backups and clean install your OS's.